# Django: Unable to set custom id in CheckboxSelectMultiple widget

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a `MultipleChoiceField` with a `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget where I want the checkboxes to have custom ids. I am creating the field in the form's `__init__` function. This is the relevant code -

```
choice_id = 'q_{}'.format(question.id)   # no issues here
self.fields['response_choices'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
                                            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'id': choice_id}), 
                                            label='',
                                            choices=choices, 
                                            required=False
                                        )
```

This doesn't work. I did the same for `ChoiceField` with `RadioSelect` widget and it works there. Is there any other attribute I need to set for `MultipleChoiceField`?

Answer (score 0):

wont let me comment but try adding primary_key=True then it shouldn't automatically set id.

Comment: what about,   self.custom_id = choice_id